# Any plugin for playing all mov, mp4 and wmv files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video, jwplayer

I am developing an Asp.Net application and I need to play all `.mov, .wmv` and `.mp4` files. Are there any softwares/plugins available to do this? I had a look at jwplayer but it only allows to play .flv and .mp4 files. I need support for all of the above three file formats.

If any player doesn't support then can you suggest any utility which we can run from c# similar to command line commands (using Process class) and get the desired format?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a flash player that supports all formats you need, but you can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) to convert your videos to .flv

Answer (score 0):

i think vlc media player plugin  will work try this link it may help https://gist.github.com/101357